ubuntu gnome boot to kde default
Ok quick question. I have gnome dsktop installed. I want to swap to kde. I've installed kde-full but i'm still booting into the gnome Desktop. Is there any way of selecting kde instead of gnome?

From your question I get that you have installed KDE but haven't set the default DM (Display Manager. More on them here: https://itsfoss.com/display-manager/) to SSDM (default DM for KDE). Therefore you boot into the GDM DM. To then go into KDE desktop, you will have locate a "settings" icon on the bottom right of the screen when you login. There you will see multiple options (ie Ubuntu, KDE). Press on the one that you want to use for the current session.

You select which DE (desktop) you use when you login; ie. at the greeter or login screen. How this is done is specific to what DM you're using; myself I'm using sddm as my greeter, whilst I also have installed gdm3 & lightdm due to other desktops I have installed; but I find sddm better suits me (besides GDM3 is somewhat tied to GNOME and I'm mostly use other desktops and not GNOME). You've not said what DM you selected to use, as that will determine HOW you select other desktops.  If you've setup your system as autologin, you need to logout & then can select another DE/WM choice.
